# What is global throttle in sentinel and how to use it?

Tags: laravel-5, sentinel

I'm working on laravel project. where I used sentinel package for authentication. In throttle ,there are three type user ,ip and global. I just want to know what is global throttle and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The global throttle is shared by all requests, regardless of user/IP.

This can be useful for things like distributed denial-of-service attacks.

Comment: My global field always show NULL value. How to use global throttle.

Comment: Do you *need* a global throttle? It's not surprising it's `NULL` by default - a global throttle has the potential to shut your entire site down if it's not set appropriately to something that won't trigger from normal traffic levels.